# How do I insert bar lines in mensural style in LilyPond?

Tags: lilypond

I'm playing with LilyPond and was attempting to typeset some of Fux's *Gradus Ad Parnassum*. As far as I can tell, Fux uses what LilyPond calls mensural style for note heads, clefs, time signatures, etc.; he also uses bar lines. LilyPond, conversely, does not display bar lines within the context MensuralStaff. (I realise that Fux is considerably later than the period associated with this notational style; I'm just going by the look of his scores.) Any tips? Here is my code:

```
lowerStaff = \new MensuralStaff = "lowerStaff" <<
  \context MensuralVoice <<
    \set Staff.forceClef = ##t
    \clef "mensural-c1"
    \time 2/2
    \relative{ a'1 a g a b c c b d cis d\breve}
  >>
>>

\paper {
  line-thickness = #(/ staff-space 5.0)
}

\score {
  <<
    \lowerStaff
  >>
  \layout {
    indent = 0.0
    line-width = 17.25\cm
    \context {
      \Score
      timing = ##f
    }
    \context {
      \MensuralVoice
      \override NoteHead.style = #'mensural
      \override Rest.style = #'mensural
      \override Flag.style = #'mensural
      \override Stem.thickness = #1.0
    }
    \context {
      \MensuralStaff
      \override KeySignature.glyph-name-alist = #alteration-mensural-glyph-name-alist
      % \override BarLine.transparent = #f
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean by "mensural bars" the bar lines only appearing between the systems, this snippet was taken from lilypond documentation:

```
global = {
  \hide Staff.BarLine % suppress barlines within the systems
   s1 s
  % the final bar line is not interrupted
  \undo \hide Staff.BarLine 
   \bar "|."
}
```

I'm not sure, how one would integrate that into your code.

Comment: Thanks, but that's not it, I'm afraid. I'm just referring to standard bar lines, as found within the stave in modern notation.

Answer (score 1):

Well, one way would be to manually add them.  You almost had the start of it:

```
\context {
  \MensuralStaff
  \override KeySignature.glyph-name-alist = #alteration-mensural-glyph-name-alist
  \override BarLine.transparent = ##f % Notice two pound signs
}
```

Then you can add the bar lines:

```
\relative{ a'1 \bar "|" a g a b c c b d cis d\breve}
```

You still have to make the bar lines thinner, and it's a pain inserting all those bar lines, but maybe it's what you have to do.

Comment: Ah, thanks very much, didn't realise the thing about the two pound signs. In the meantime I had fudged it by using the standard settings with no fancy contexts, and overriding just the styles of note head, rest, time signature, etc. But this is better.